# Html tags inserted to MySQL changed

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form with POST method, one of element is a text input, which can contain html code as a value. I need to save this value to mysql database.
This is without troubles on my local server, but on our hosting server (with different versions of php and MySQL) the code from input was changed after the insert.

E. g. for value `<ul><li>a</li><li>b</li></ul>` in DB is saved "- a - b"

How to solve that correctly?

Edit - more info: project is on wordpress, using wpdb for communication with database.

Form field:

```
<textarea name="description" value=""></textarea>
```

getting value and inserting to db:

```
$description = $_POST ["description"];

      $wpdb->insert( 
                'attribute', 
                array( 
                    'name' => $name, 
                    'description' => $description,
                    'attribute_order' => $order,
                    'section_id' => $section_id
                ) 
              );
```

Comment: Data doesn't get altered without you instructing it to be altered. And without seeing your code, hard to say.

Comment: @JanaMaha share more details like code & db screenshots to get more clearly

Comment: How are you viewing the data? Maybe you are outputting to a browser so the content is rendered rather than displayed?

Comment: I cant repeat this behavior, dont understand that. I spent a hour with that and now it is working in original state.

Comment: @user3783243 the formatted value was in db, seen through phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape it if you want to save unformatted value

Check the [Entity name](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html) of each characters